# Loading trie first time the app opens

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a custom ios keyboard. For the dictionary of words, I have implemented trie for autocorrect. Trie is coded in objective c as well. I have 100k wordlist. I want to load the trie only the first time the app opens and it should get stored permanently. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with loading only once, downloading?

Given that you download the data (let's assume as a txt from the internet) you can build up your trie and serialize that via NSKeyedArchiver and also restore it.

```
Trie *wordsTrie = [[Trie alloc]initWithUrl:@"https://www.internet.com/words.txt"]];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:wordsTrie];

/* persist the data ... */

Trie *restoredWordsTrie = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

More about archiving objects can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Archiving.html

Comment: I have custom trie and I setup/load the trie from a txt file. Whenever my keyboard pops up, I would have to load the trie which takes 2-3 seconds. So there is a lag for the keyboard to appear. Instead, only for the very first time the keyboard pops up, the trie should be loaded. From the next time the when keyboard pops up, it should read the trie which is already loaded. Just like userdefaults we need to store the trie permanently

Comment: Sorry to say that but that's a very generic problem statement. There are multiple aspects here: loading the entire trie into memory on start might increase the actual lookup time but I would reconsider to implement a proxy pattern and maybe just load the first 3 levels and then load subtrees when needed (pick a random algorithm book for further implementation).

Comment: Additionally: how do you implement your Trie? Is every node an object?

Comment: Can't we store the Trie into NSUserDefaults and restore the trie whenever the keyboard pops up?

Comment: I wonder how other keyboards like GBoard, wordFlow manages the dictionary. I believe they use Trie but not sure how they are loading it so quick

Comment: You may consider to use an array-based structure instead, which is definitely faster to initialize but could be harder to implement correctly (e.g. https://linux.thai.net/~thep/datrie/datrie.html)

Comment: I haven't implemented a custom keyboard yet, can't you write into any kind of persistent storage? If you can, just write out the archived trie as shown in my initial answer. Recreating the original object structure (especially if you have tens of thousands of objects) might still take some time so you should definitely look into an array based strategy (Skiena has a good explanation for this)